# Mysql query in multiple row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I create a project with `laravel 5.4` and `mysql 5.7` database . i have two role in this project named driver and customer.

In my project a driver can select multiple skills and add multiple tags for each skill and a customer can register a order with multiple items . in order_items each item can bind to a skill and multiple tags

Notice :  user `skill_id` have 4 part `Group - Category - Subcategory - Item` and each part of `skill_id` explain of skill level for example skill_id like `G1-C2-S3` mean user selected all items of this level because user just selected three level

Another example skill_id `G5-C5-S2-T7` in this skill user just selected item7 of subcategory2 of category5 of group5

Notice : user `skill_id` level parts is not fix

User Skills have table like below  :

```
 skill_id      user_id
 ________________________
  G1-C2-S3       2
  G2-C4          2
  G5-C5-S2-T7    2
```

A user skills tags Table

```
 skill_id      user_id    tag
 _______________________________
  G1-C2-S3       2         nice
  G1-C2-S3       2         good
  G1-C2-S3       2          bad
  G2-C4          2          xxx
  G2-C4          2          yyy
  G5-C5-S2-T7    2          zz
  G5-C5-S2-T7    2          jjj
```

Order table is :

```
 id      title     
 ________________
  3      egergr    
  3      ergervv     
  3      ergerger
```

Order items table is :

```
    item_id      order_id      tags
 __________________________________
  G1-C2-S3-t2       3         nice
  G2-C4-S6-t3       3          yyy
  G5-C5-S2-T7       3          zz
```

Notic : a user in register order can select last level of skill_id for each item so `item_id` is always 4 part of skill and it's fix

How can i write a query that bind a customer order to a driver with matched skills and his tags to a order items and his tags?

I wrote below code but not works

```
$skills = UsersSkills::with('tags')->where('user_id',$biker_id)->get();

    $revisions = function ($query) use($skills) 
    {
        foreach($skills as $skill)
        {

            $tags = ($skills[0]['tags']->toArray() !== []) ? $skills[0]['tags']->toArray() : null;
            $tags_values = (!is_null($tags)) ? array_column($tags, 'tag') : null;
            $query->where('item_id','LIKE',$skills[0]['skill_id'].'%')->whereIn('tags',$tags_values);
        }
    };

    $orders = Order::whereHas('order_items', $revisions)->where(function($query) use($maxLat,$minLat,$maxLon,$minLon,$biker_search_time,$estimation_id) {

        $query->where('done_by_expert',1);
        $query->whereBetween('destination_longitude', [$minLon, $maxLon]);
        $query->whereBetween('destination_latitude',[$minLat,$maxLat]);
        $query->where('status','=','pending');
        $query->where('type','=',NULL);
        $query->where('vehicle_type_id',$estimation_id);
        $query->whereNull('favorites');
        $query->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subMinute($biker_search_time));


    })->get();
```

Comment: You should use [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between `User` and `Skill` models.

Comment: not works  , order items What will be

Comment: _"but not works"_ means what? What exactly do you expect from that piece of code, and what is the actual (unexpected) output/behaviour?

Comment: strip it down to a minimal example. reduce the steps to tiny bits of code and see what parts do what you expect and what parts don't. This now is too much for us to be ask to debug, because _"but not works"_.

Comment: order have multiple items and user have multiple skills  that piece of code must match each `item_id` and his tag to user `skill_id` and his tags and if all item_id and his tag matched to user skills and his tags that driver can take that order

Comment: _"multiple skills that piece of code must match"_ - use interpunctuation!! It's your friend!

Comment: again:  reduce the steps to tiny bits of code and see what parts do what you expect and what parts don't

Comment: Either you're decades ahead of us, or this is a really bad idea